# Get the change log report from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this query :

```
SELECT 
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, 
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, 
    EM.* 
FROM
    CHANGETABLE (CHANGES [A_Table], 0) AS CT 
JOIN 
    [dbo].[A_Table] EM ON CT.A_Primary_KEY1 = EM.A_Primary_KEY1 
                       AND CT.A_Primary_KEY2 = EM.A_Primary_KEY2 
                       AND CT.A_Primary_KEY3 = EM.A_Primary_KEY3
ORDER BY 
    SYS_CHANGE_VERSION
```

I'm getting only the version which is changed to the table. I need to get the previous version and current version of the changed record(before changing and after changing of the record). Please do help me. TIA

Comment: Please provide sample ata and desired results.

Comment: The data is bit confidential. So, I've not included any result output. I just need the previous version of the changed data record and the current version of the changed data record with datetime mode.

Comment: Change tracking cannot provide the previous values. It only shows that changes have been made (rows which have been changed). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#Tracking

Comment: Please provide me some detail as I've mentioned the requirement of the changelog for my application.